# "Always on top" feature for Mac

Tags: mac

Ubuntu has a feature where application windows can be set to be always on top of other windows. Is this possible in Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/).

> **it will add many window management features to most Mac applications:**
>
> - Keep windows afloat (heh) on top of all others.
> - Pin windows to the desktop (new!)
> - Move windows from anywhere, not just the title bar.
> - Turn a window into an "overlay" on your screen that doesn't hinder your
>     work.
> - Show a window's file in the Finder with nothing more than your keyboard.
> - Resize windows from anywhere, not just the corner (new!), and more.

Afloat is freeware.